# I want to boot my computere through nic card like a novell netware

Tags: active-directory

I have one client computer. In that PC no hdd and  I want to boot from server thorugh NIC card like use Older version (Novell Netware).

In the server MS2003 server OS. Is there any option to boot from server.

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to PXE booting Windows. There is no supported way to do this with standard Windows client operating systems.

You *can* do this with something like WinCE or Windows Embedded in thin clients, but that's most likely not what you're looking for.